# How to return a list from a function?

Tags: haskell

I have this function in Haskell to get perfect numbers. I want to return a list of perfect numbers.

```
perfect :: Int -> []
perfect digit  = [presentNum | presentNum <- [1..digit], isPerfect presentNum]

isPerfect :: Integer -> Bool   --function declaration 
isPerfect n =  n == sum [i | i <- [1..n-1], n `mod` i == 0]
```

but I am met with the error

> - Expecting one more argument to `[]'
>      Expected a type, but`[]' has kind `* -> *'
> - In the type signature: perfect :: Int -> []

How do I properly return a list?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to specify the type of the list elements:

```
perfect :: Int -> [Int]
                -- ^^^ --
```

There is no type of "lists" `[]`, but only types such as "list of integers" `[Int]`, "list of strings" `[String]` and so on.

Technically, Haskell does allow `[]` as a *type constructor* of kind `* -> *` (that's what the error reports), making `[]` not a type but something that takes a type like `Int` and returns a type `[Int]`. So, roughly, `[]` is a function from types to types, not a type.

Answer (score 5):

The *type signature* is wrong. If you return a list of `Int`s, then it should be `[Int]` (or `[] Int`):

```
perfect :: Int -> [Int]
perfect digit = [presentNum | presentNum <- [1..digit], isPerfect presentNum]
```

Here it might however be easier to work with [**`filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter):

```
perfect :: Int -> [Int]
perfect digit = filter isPerfect [1..digit]
```

We can work with [**`enumFromTo :: Enum a => a -> a -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:enumFromTo) to make a point-free implementation"

```
perfect :: Int -> [Int]
perfect = filter isPerfect . enumFromTo 1
```